# additional fields I added in local storage getting overwritten in cart

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, local-storage, e-commerce

I am building an e-commerce website in React and Node js. I am having trouble with local storage and my shopping cart. I have some fields that i've added to local storage (size and finish) that you can select on the product page:

This is an example of a product with that functionality:

http://157.245.95.222/product/5d3f2a189330283e54b41a66

This is the function that adds the item to the cart.

```
export const addItem = (item, count, finish, size, next) => {
    let cart = []
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if(localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
        }
        cart.push({
            ...item,
            count: count,
            finish: finish,
            size: size
        })

        cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
            console.log(cart)
            return cart.find(p => p._id === id)
        })

        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))
        next()
    }
}
```

however, the block of code in the addItem function:

```
cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
            console.log(cart)
            return cart.find(p => p._id === id)
        })
```

that prevents you from adding the same item overwrites the item  with the same product id. (If you select Honed Arabescato and add it to the cart, then go back and select Polished Arabescato, you will only see the polished version). I am trying to figure out how you can add both to the cart. If I comment out the above code ^, the same item is added to the cart many times, and the overwriting happens to all of them. How would I go about being able to add the different variations to the cart?

My code can be seen here: 
(Front End)
https://github.com/Arunscape224/sgi_4.0_client
(Backend)
https://github.com/Arunscape224/sgi_4.0

I've tried commenting out the new Set, as this is what allows only one copy of that product to be added to the cart array. Ideally, I want to be able to add the same product with different finishes to the cart.

```
export const addItem = (item, count, finish, size, next) => {
    let cart = []
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if(localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
        }
        cart.push({
            ...item,
            count: count,
            finish: finish,
            size: size
        })

        cart = Array.from(new Set(cart.map(p => p._id))).map(id => {
            console.log(cart)
            return cart.find(p => p._id === id)
        })

        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))
        next()
    }
}
```

By commenting the Array.from block within the addItem function, I expected the different versions of the product to be added to the cart. I did not expect it to overwrite the product in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are setting your id field.  Is it possible that null === null is your only match?